# declaring dynamic knockout observable in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am implementing knockout with asp.net mvc where i have a viewmodel in asp.net mvc. I have a list of array generated using server side based on the value of property name of each class in asp.net mvc view model. eg: Array[] propertyName = { name1, name2, name3 }. Now i need to make all this property Name observable as follow. I could type it 1 by 1 in javascript, but the problem is it should be dynamic according to property available in view model defined in asp.net mvc. Now i am hardcodng name1, name2, name3 buy i do not know how to make it dynamic according to the array return from server.

```js
<script>
  function TestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.name1 = ko.observable('@name1') //from view model (need to be dynamic)
    self.name2 = ko.observable('@name2') //from view model (need to be dynamic)
    self.name3 = ko.observable('@name3') //from view model (need to be dynamic)
    
    self.btn1 = ko.observable(false); //hardcoded base on html
    self.btn2 = ko.observable(true); //hardcoded base on html
  }
  
    ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
</script>


// What i expect
<script>
  function TestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    Array[] propertyName = { name1, name2, name3 } // value retrieve from server
    @foreach(var item in propertyName) {
      // and knockout js can run this
      self.@propertyName = ko.observable(@propertyName)
    }
    
    self.btn1 = ko.observable(false); //hardcoded base on html
    self.btn2 = ko.observable(true); //hardcoded base on html
  }
  
    ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
</script>

// fail because self.@propertyName
self.@propertyName = ko.observable(@propertyName)
= expected identifer
ko expected;
```

Comment: What's not working with what you tried?

Comment: @haim770 lets assume a single variable @@propertyName = name1
self.anystring = ko.applyBindings(@@propertyName) works but not
self.@@propertyName = ko.applyBindings(@@propertyName) will have syntax error

i want left hand side to be dynamic as well

Comment: @haim770 cannot assign dynamic property from server to lhs

Comment: You can try `self.@(PropertyName) = ...` or `self['@PropertyName'] = ...`

Comment: Although it's unclear to me how exactly you're going to write your `data-bind` attributes if you can't expect a known view-model structure in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin for creating ko.observables based on your model properties.
So suppose, if you have a the following model that you pass to your razor view

```
 public class PersonVM
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
 }
```

then you can use serialize the model as json object and pass to your TestViewModel function, and use ko.mapping.fromJs(data,{},this) to map the C# model properties to your client knockout viewmodel observables.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function TestViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
            self.btn1 = ko.observable(false); //hardcoded base on html
            self.btn2 = ko.observable(true); //hardcoded base on html
        }

        var jsonEncodedModel = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
        ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel(jsonEncodedModel));

</script>
```

Then your model properties Id, Name, Address will created as observables in your TestViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should call the server when the page is loaded. For instance:

```
function TestViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();

    //call server to load the items
    $.ajax({
       url: 'someUrl',
       data: 'someValueFromTheView'
    }).done(function (result) {
        self.items(result);

    });
};

//run the bindings when the page is loaded
$(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new TestViewModel());
});
```